# iPhone - button within cell to push a new view onto screen

Tags: ios4, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, addsubview

Hey guys, I appear to have run into a problem. I have an application (View-based) that has a UITableView displayed on the bottom half of the screen, with the selection of a cell then bringing up a custom cell taking up the bottom of the screen. I have a "more info" button on the bottom right of this cell, and and when it is selected, I wish for it to open a new NIB file, however the only thing I can manage to do is remove the tableView from the screen..I am not sure of what to use before the "addSubview" because it is not self.view which I thought it would be.

```
- (void)moreInfoButton:(id)selector{
    NSLog(@"Button Pressed");
    MoreInfo *mivc = [[MoreInfo alloc] initWithNibName:@"MoreInfo" bundle:nil];
    [self.tableview removeFromSuperview];
    //[self.view addSubview:(UIView *)mivc];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mivc animated:YES];
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"List of Events" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
    [backButton release];
    [mivc release];

}
```

Also, the (UIView *) doesn't do the trick either. Any suggestions?

P.S. The UITableView does not use a navigationController at all, it is just the table, would this be the problem?

Also, what if I chose to just push a new view, and not use the navigationViewController for this view, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't answer your navigation controller question without seeing more of your program. To answer your other question, without using a navigation controller you can just add a new view with:

```
newViewVC = [[NewViewVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"NewViewVC" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:newViewVC.view];
```

Typically newViewVC is declared in your .h so you can release it later.

Comment: when using this way, in the NewViewVC, I have a button to return to the previous view with its content just being [self.view removeFromSuperview], however it will only close when it is tapped twice, any reason why?

Comment: One thing that would cause that would be if you are somehow instantiating and adding NewViewVC twice. 

If you have not seen them already check out the Stanford videos for iPhone application development: [link](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewPodcast?id=384233225)

Answer (score 0):

I have found an easy way: pushing it as a modal.

```
- (void)moreInfoButton:(id)selector{
    NSLog(@"Button Pressed");
    MoreInfo *mi= [[MoreInfo alloc] initWithNibName:@"MoreInfo" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:mi animated:YES];
}
```

All that is needed is a back button in the new nib file.